# libgfortran.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

Can you help me to go out from these error. It was a nightmare when i tried to solve it. Where is the error please?

```
 File "/project/6008168/tamouze/Python_directory/lda2vec/examples/twenty_newsgroups/lda2vec/lda2vec_run.py", line 18, in <module>
    from lda2vec import utils
  File "/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lda2vec/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tracking
  File "/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lda2vec/tracking.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
  File "/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.19.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/__init__.py", line 134, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.19.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/base.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .utils.fixes import signature
  File "/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.19.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .validation import (as_float_array,
  File "/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.19.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 18, in <module>
    from ..utils.fixes import signature
  File "/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.19.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/sklearn/utils/fixes.py", line 144, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import lsqr as sparse_lsqr  # noqa
  File "/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-1.1.0rc1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/sparse/linalg/__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from .isolve import *
  File "/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-1.1.0rc1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .iterative import *
  File "/home/tamouze/anaconda2/envs/testing-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy-1.1.0rc1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/scipy/sparse/linalg/isolve/iterative.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import _iterative
ImportError: libgfortran.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

im working on the following system:

```
Linux cdr352.int.cedar.computecanada.ca 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 01:06:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
Release:        7.4.1708
Codename:       Core
```

it is an ssh server.

Comment: `libgfortran.so.4` : gcc-7.x creates libgfortran.so.4 : `--enable-languages=c,c++,fortran` .... Please edit your question to include the OS you are using. Example, CentOS7 ( cr repo ): `yum install libgfortran4`.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Linux cdr352.int.cedar.computecanada.ca 3.10.0-693.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jan 4 01:06:37 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @KnudLarsenDistributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
Release:        7.4.1708
Codename:       Core

Answer (score 1):

> CentOS 7.4.1708

`/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-CR.repo` is a text file: Please edit `enabled=0` to `enabled=1` ... ... ( Example: `# gedit /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-CR.repo` )

Then you can do : `# yum install libgfortran4`

---

All default repo´s http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/

CR.repo http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.4.1708/cr/x86_64/Packages/

---

EDIT 2019 : libgfortran4 is now in the default repo → `# yum install libgfortran4` will work with default repo entries.

Comment: i cant edit, when type: gedit /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-CR.repo, i get You need to be root to perform this command.

Comment: Well, then download the package, and unpack to get the file = `libgfortran.so.4.0.0`.

Comment: 2019 : Today, `libgfortran4` is in the default repo (updates) http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.6.1810/updates/x86_64/Packages/ ... (and os/ : http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/ ), so please do `# yum install libgfortran4`

Answer (score -2):

This is because gcc including fortran which included libgfortran hasn't installed.

By running the below command 
   apt-get install gfortran

Should fix the issue most probably.